# How to change unity CharacterController center in script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to change `CharacterController.center`, but failed:

```
CharacterController character = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterController>();

character.center.Set(0, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    CharacterController controller;
    private void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        controller.center = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    }
}
```

Read the scripting wiki from Unity. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/